# How to access files on Parse.com from Parse Server

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

My app used Parse.com as a backend to serve audio files and PDF files to users.  Now I have migrated to Parse Server on Heroku.  The console says "code 1, internal server error."

My question:  Is it not possible to access the files I have on Parse.com from Parse Server?  Or it is possible and I'm not doing it right?

Thank you,

Eli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to get your apps "fileKey" from the Parse Dashboard.
You need to include this key together with your appId, databaseUrl e.t.c. as you have inside of your ParseServer initialization code on the server.

Everything would work just fine after this.